# Python portable-версия для windows чтобы делиться с другими пользователями и запускать код без прав администратора

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Я только учусь Python и прошу не стесняться говорить попроще.

В интернете видел некие портативные сборки Python и решил что можно так сделать чтобы стало возможным давать коллегам по офису папку где будет лежать файл ".py" либо ".ipynb" и там же разместить папку для запуска этого файла с портативной версией Python с библиотеками. Пользователь без прав администратора скопирует к себе на компьютер (windows) эту папку и без каких-либо настроек выполнить скрипт ".py" либо ".ipynb".
Задавшись столь благородной целью, качаю Python тут:
[Ссылка на портативную сборку Python](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portable-python/files/)

Даю эти команды в консоль:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install jupyterlab
python -m pip install mitoinstaller
python -m mitoinstaller install
```

И здесь начинаются проблемы - любая строка из этого набора команд pip (даже одна) рушит мою идею, папка становится не портативной (переименовать ее тоже нельзя).

Пробовал создавать виртуальное окружение и ставить библиотеки в него:

```
python -m venv NAME
NAME\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Тоже не помогло.
Скажите какими действиями я могу собрать портативную сборку с этими библиотеками.

Если это не возможно, и так просто делиться с другими пользователями я скриптами Python не смогу, то какая есть у меня альтернатива чтобы делиться кодом Python с другими пользователями (в т.ч. без прав администратора) и при это сохранять возможность работать с локальной файловой системой?

Рассматривал варинаты:

1. Установка anaconda (ставится без прав админа) - не подходит, пользователей слишком много, сложно для простых пользователей.
2. Обычный python на локальной машине или виртуально через Docker: не подходит - требуются прав админа, сложно для простых пользователей.
3. Выполнение кода в облаке (google colab, binder): не подходит, требуется работа с локальными файлами (в корпоративной сети), которые не разрешено залить в облако.
4. Локальный веб-сервер с установленным Python выдающий результат запуска скриптов через Localhost: не подходит по совокупности разных причин, главная из которых в том, что я ищу решения проще и возлагаю надежду на портативную сборку, которая лучше подходит под мои цели.

Comment: Как вариант компилировать скрипты в исполняемые файлы с помощью pyinstaller (подойдёт не для всяких скриптов, не дружит с многими сторонними библиотеками). Как второй вариант - использовать для скриптинга не python, а golang. Он такой же простой при изучении  и использовании для простого скриптинга, как и python. Скрипты из коробки компилируются в исполняемые файлы для любой платформы.

Comment: Два вопроса разрешите.
Вопрос 1. В чем смысл псевдопортативных питонов (таких как по этой ссылке: https://sourceforge.net/projects/portable-python/files/) если на деле портировать его не удается?Мне кажется я что-то перестал понимать. Вопрос 2. Pyinstaller будет работать с локальной файловой системой или он скопирует все файлы как зависимость к себе внутрь (куда-то внуть .EXE или что он там создаст) после чего обновление данных локальных файлов, лежащих, скажем, где-то на сетевом диске, перестанет отражаться на результатах скрипта?

Comment: Вопрос 3. Кроме golang какие еще языки подойдут? Наверное, задавая этот вопрос, я хотел узнать  про Rust , есть ли у него исполняемые файлы для любой платформы?

Comment: Смысл портативного Питона, как я понимаю, в переносимости простым копированием директории с ним. При этом он не будет установлен в систему, к нему не будет прописана переменная среды. И запуская его из консоли, придётся писать полный путь к интерпретатору, а не просто команду 'python'.

Comment: Вы, когда пишете у себя в консоли 'python -bla-bla', вызываете таким образом системный Python, не портативный.

Comment: Pyinstaller запакует в exe-файл то, что вы ему скажете. Работать с файловой системой будет так, как пропишете в коде.

Comment: Про Rust не подскажу, не пробовал. Но он наверняка сложнее в изучении, чем Go.